# Remove end folder part of string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say if we have this string

```
a = 'C:/my_folder/folder/mac/data/';
```

How can I use regexprep to reduce the string to:

```
'C:/my_folder/folder/mac/';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to do it.

```
[pathstr] = fileparts(a);
regexprep(pathstr, '(?<=/)[^/]*$', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to cut 5 char at end of string
    a = a(1:end-5)

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how long the folder will be in terms of the name so I can't use that.